# I am not able to use start date and end date in clear airflow through CLI

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have been trying to clear a task using the following command.
airflow clear -t <task_name> -s <start_date> -e <end_date> <dag_name>

eg: `airflow clear -t <task_name> -s 2020-06-22 -e 2020-06-22 <dag_name>`

I have also tried to use start date and end date with all the following combinations:

1. `'2020-06-22'`
2. `'2020-06-22 10:21:23'`
3. `2020-06-23T10:28:15`
4. `2020-06-23T07:44:27.814321+00:00`

None of these combinations is working for me. I don't understand how to use start_date and end_date with the clear command. I also want to know if we can clear the tasks between the start date and end date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dateformat YYYY-mm-dd is correct but tasks to be clear should be within `start_date <= {execution date of the tasks} < end_date` so you need to change your end_date.

```
airflow clear -s 2020-06-22 -e 2020-06-23 sample_dag
```

This will clear all tasks within `sample_dag`.

If you want to clear a specific task(s) within the `sample_dag`, you can use the `-t` option. `-t` option takes the regex, for example

```
airflow clear -t etl -s 2020-06-22 -e 2020-06-23 sample_dag
```

will clear all tasks that contains "etl" in task_id.